# How to use command prompt via vb.net to use BCDEDIT

Tags: vb.net

I have a batch file which contains some commands with bcdedit.
but in my vb.net application when I run that batch file via: Process.Start("CMD", " /C \blahblah\test.bat") it says bcdedit is not recognized.

so what I've found so far is the cmd.exe that vb.net opens it doesn't recognize bcdedit command at all.

Comment: The environment variables probably aren't loaded.  Either load them, set the PATH variable, or specify the full path to bcdedit.exe in your bat file.

Comment: Try with `Dim proc as Process = new Process() proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe" proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C ..." proc.Start()`. Check what you have in `proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`

Comment: The problem is even when I just open the cmd.exe and go to System32 it doesn't recognize bcdedit.exe
https://imgur.com/wc2VIva

Comment: The problem got solved by choosing X64 when I want to compile my application in visual studio.